# What is the "round" tripod plate used for?

Tags: tripod

I have recently purchased a new tripod [(Oben AC-1400 AL with BA-00 HEAD)](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/687334-REG/Oben_AC_1400_BA_00_AC_1400_4_Section_Aluminum_Tripod.html) and there is a round plate between the tripod and the head itself. It seems like it is meant to remain where it is but **I think the head is more secure without it** as it catches more thread on the screw the connects the tripod and the head.

Is the round plate necessary? what is it's purpose?

[image]

[image]

Edit: Added a model name, link and a picture showing the location of the plate.

[image]

Edit: Added a new image to show the screws on the plate and that they do not extend into any opening in the head itself.

Comment: What is the make and model? Did you read the manual? Did you visit manufacturers website to research, and possibly ask customer service?

Comment: Added a link and model, also an image showing the location of the plate. Can't find the manufacturer website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How does a head lock onto the tripod? Normally, you would screw the head onto the plate with a protruding 3/8"(?) screw, then beneath the plate where you screwed the tripod onto are three set screws that are screwed down to tighten against the head. Basically, the head is screwed on in one direction and the set screws push in the opposite direction. This creates a "lock" so that the head doesn't somehow work it's way loose, probably at the most inopportune time!

The round plate you picture looks like the plate I describe. There are three set screws, likely to push against the head. If you remove this plate, how does the head stay locked on the tripod? (I'm asking. I'm not familiar with this tripod so I don't know.) This round plate appears to have a hex center hole. I'm guessing that the hex center hole lines up on the tripod, so that this round plate can't spin. Then you screw the head onto the plate/tripod, and then you tighten the three set screws on this round plate.

Comment: Thanks! You might be right. I didn't see any corresponding holes for the screws on the bottom of the head itself but screwing the set of screws further into the bottom of the head will make it more secure. I will add a new image to show where the screw comes up on the other side but i think that's what i need to do.

Comment: The set screws push against the flat surface, not go into a hole.  Use lok-tite thread goo and the deeper screw. If you end up turning that screw instead of working the pan joint, you have a long way to go before it falls off.  Thread locker comes in different strengths so make sure it's harder to turn than you might do accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

My Bogen head has a circular plate that looks like that. There's a matching disk on the tripod, with a scalloped or sawtooth pattern. The three set screws near the edge of the plate engage the scallops on the tripod to prevent the head from rotating on the main screw. If your tripod doesn't have a plate to match the one on the head, then I don't see the point of the plate.

Comment: No doesn't really match. It almost seems redundant. The screw has a hexagonal nut in the middle that fits into the hole (see above) but the problem is that see is that if I have the plate there I don't think the screw protrudes enough for the head to have a good grip (3/4 of a turn) Just feels like it could loosen.  The other issue is that the head rotates and it is easy to accidentally loosen it with the round plate in there. I might just take it out...

Answer (score 1):

Since the top of the column doesn't end in a flange, what is the head tightened against? That part is a nut that (even without the locking screws) can be tighened against the head to lock them in place.  Otherwise what is makingnit tight— just the screw bottoming out?